# Demo Events Source

Tags: fullcalendar

My template came with FullCalendar and the the calendar is showing demo events - I am trying to find out where they come from - where can I change the source from - basically I want a blank Calendar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove

```
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.eventSource, $scope.eventsF];
```

This line from your js file, Calendar will not have any event rendered on it..!!

Happy Coding....:)